# How to set up golang client for Google Calendar APIs using a service account

Tags: go, google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I've seen lots of documentation on Google API clients for users, but very little on using a service account. This isn't on behalf of a user, I'm just trying to get a client working with the Calendar APIs using a client ID and client secret, which would be provided via environment variables for me (I'd prefer to not read from a file).

Here's what I have so far:

```golang
package main

import (
  "context"

  clientCredentials "golang.org/x/oauth2/clientcredentials"
  google "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
  calendar "google.golang.org/api/calendar/v3"
  apiOption "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

func main() {
  config := &clientCredentials.Config{
    ClientID:     "<my_id>",
    ClientSecret: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...",
    TokenURL:     google.Endpoint.TokenURL,
  }
  ctx := context.Background()
  client := config.Client(ctx)
  service, _ := calendar.NewService(ctx, apiOption.WithHTTPClient(client))
  
  calendarList, err := service.CalendarList.List().Do()
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Get "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?alt=json&prettyPrint=false": oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request
Response: {
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: client_credentials"
}
```

Any help here is greatly appreciated! I'm new to Golang, Oauth2, and Google APIs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @Tanaike got me on the right track. This is what I ended up using:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    googleOauth "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    calendar "google.golang.org/api/calendar/v3"
    apiOption "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

var service *calendar.Service

// Note that some of the fields are optional:
type GoogleAuthConfig struct {
    Type                string `json:"type"`
    ProjectID           string `json:"project_id,omitempty"`
    ClientEmail         string `json:"client_email"`
    ClientID            string `json:"client_id,omitempty"`
    ClientSecret        string `json:"private_key"`
    ClientSecretID      string `json:"private_key_id,omitempty"`
    AuthURL             string `json:"auth_uri,omitempty"`
    TokenURL            string `json:"token_uri,omitempty"`
    AuthProviderCertURL string `json:"auth_provider_x509_cert_url,omitempty"`
    ClientCertURL       string `json:"client_x509_cert_url,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    authConfig := GoogleAuthConfig{
        Type:         "service_account",
        ClientEmail:  "account123@project-456.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        ClientID:     "1234",
        ClientSecret: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
        AuthURL:      googleOauth.Endpoint.AuthURL,
        TokenURL:     googleOauth.Endpoint.TokenURL,
    }
    authConfigJson, err := json.Marshal(authConfig)

    ctx := context.Background()
    service, err = calendar.NewService(ctx, apiOption.WithCredentialsJSON([]byte(authConfigJson)))
}
```

Note that I didn't have to configure domain-wide delegation or impersonate a user; this worked fine after I added the service account to the calendar.

Service accounts still need to accept calendar invites after you add the account email to the calendar. This can be done with the following:

```
entry := calendar.CalendarListEntry{Id: calendarID}
service.CalendarList.Insert(&entry).Do()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to access Google Calendar using the service account with golang.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    calendar "google.golang.org/api/calendar/v3"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    v := `{"type": "service_account", "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n###\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "client_email": "###"}`
    service, _ := calendar.NewService(ctx, option.WithCredentialsJSON([]byte(v)))
    calendarList, _ := service.CalendarList.List().Do()
    fmt.Println(calendarList)
}
```

- If you want to use the file including the credential information, please modify it as follows.

  ```
    service, _ := calendar.NewService(ctx, option.WithCredentialsFile(credentialFile))
  ```

#### Note:

- If you want to retrieve the Google Calendar of your account, please share your Google Calendar with the email of the service account.
- Linda Lawton - DaImTo's comment: `Google calendar doesn't support service account for standard google users. You need to configure domain wide delegation and impersonate a user on your google workspace account. and how to add the sub to this code.`

  - References

    - https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials
    - https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/impersonate#example-CredentialsTokenSource-ServiceAccount

#### References:

- [calendar](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/calendar/v3)
- [google-api-go-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client)

Comment: can you add some notes on:  Google calendar doesn't support service account for standard google users.   You need to configure domain wide delegation and impersonate a user on  your google workspace account.   and how to add the sub to this code.

Comment: @Linda Lawton - DaImTo Thank you for your comment. I added your comment. If you have the modification points, feel free to edit them.

Comment: I dont get points for edits anymore.  We tag team a lot of these questions its all good 